# Expectation of the supremum of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, expected-value

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(0,1)$, P=Lebesgue measure.

Let $X_n(w)=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad \frac{1}{n} < w \leq 1 \\
n-n^2w \quad 0 \leq w \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$

The first part of the exercise is proving that $X_{n}$ is a martingale, which I managed to do. 
Now my problem is computing $E(sup_{n \geq 1}|X_n|)$ and I don't know how to proceed. From the solutions I know that it must be equal to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\omega ([\frac 1 {2\omega}] -\omega [\frac 1 {2\omega}]^{2}) \to \frac 1 2 -\frac 1 4=\frac 1 4$ as $\omega \to 0$. Hence for $\omega$ sufficiently small $\omega ([\frac 1 {2\omega}] -\omega [\frac 1 {2\omega}]^{2}) >\frac 1 8$. Taking $k=[\frac 1 {2\omega}]$ we see that $\sup_n |X_n(\omega)| \geq |X_k(\omega)| \geq \frac 1 {4\omega}$. Since $\int \frac 1 {4\omega}\, d \omega =\infty$ it follows that $E\sup_n |X_n(\omega)|=\infty$.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, where does the first expression come from?

Comment: Ok now i understand but i don’t get Why the value of that integral is plus infinity. Because that integral is equal to log(w)/4. Where does plus infinity comes from?

Comment: @ank13 You have to evaluate the definite integral from $0$ to $1$ to find expectation.  If $Y(\omega) \geq \frac 1 {4\omega}$ then $EY=\int_0^{1} Y(\omega)\, d\omega \geq \int_0^{1} \frac 1 {4\omega}\, d\omega =\infty$.

Comment: Ok now I understand! Thank you!